# Class Extensions in Modular JS

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, extension-methods

Say I have a generic class module:

```js
export class MyCalc {
    data = {}
    ...
}
```

And say I want to extend more functionality:

```js
export class MyCalcLoader {
    load = some_data => {
        this.data = some_data;
    }
}

export class MyCalcUI {
    print = () => {
        document.write(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    }
}
```

What is the appropriate way to extend `MyCalc` and also use those extensions/plugins?

```js
import {MyCalc} from "./MyCalc.js";
import {MyCalcLoader} from "./MyCalcLoader.js";
import {MyCalcUI} from "./MyCalcUI.js";

// TODO: MakeMyCalcExtendLoaderAndUi();

class BankingCalc extends MyCalc {
    config = {...}
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const banking_calc = new BankingCalc();
banking_calc.load({...});
banking_calc.print();
```

I've thought through a few different janky ways to do this, but I'm sure this is common enough and that there's a right way to do it with vanilla ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Mixins:

```
 export const MyCalcLoader = Super => class MyCalcLoader extends Super {
  load = some_data => {
    this.data = some_data;
  }
 }

 export const MyCalcUI = Super => class MyCalcUI extends Super {
   print = () => {
     document.write(JSON.stringify(this.data));
  }
}
```

Then compose the class as:

```
 class BankingCalc extends MyCalcLoader(MyCalcUI(MyCalc)) {
  //...
 }
```

Comment: Oh that's cleaver. Looking up 'js mixins' now, and seeing that you could make a function that assigns all the prototypes of each extension to the original class. Trying this on for size.

Comment: @phil working with the prototypes gets you in trouble with the constructors though.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So I also did this and it worked: `const banking_calc = new (MyCalcLoader(MyCalcUI(MyCalc)))({...config});`

Comment: @phil if you only need one instance then yes. If you need multiple instances you should declare a class (otherwise the instances have different prototype chains which is bad for performance)